# Dealing with big data

Tags: bigdata, software-recommendation

I am on a project dealing with a lot of data in the form of images and videos (Data related to wind engineering). My requirement is to build a predictive algorithm based on the data I have. I have found many tools with which I can analyse the data where each tool has its own advantages and disadvantages. Big data being really new to me, I find it very difficult to choose a platform to start with. There should be other people here who should have dealt with similar situations.

- What criteria should I mainly take into account before selecting a
  tool for analysing big data?

Some of the Criteria that I have taken into account : Visualization, Interaction, Security, Data Access and integration, Speed of response, Integrated Data Mining, Pattern Matching, Ease of use etc. As you can see the list that I have made for the criteria comes from the extensive reading of different articles on the topic. But I can't narrow down the list nor find the individual contribution of these criteria in the various tools available for analysis.

Let me also list some of the tools that I found after googling : Knime, Statistica 2, Rapidminer, Orange, WEKA, KEEL, R and RATTLE.

On what basis could I choose a tool from a list of tools that perform similar tasks?

**UPDATE based on Comment**

Aim : To develop a software that analyses the data coming from the wind mills and generate reports. The software should be able to predict when a wind mill can fail based on the analysis.

The project is still in the phase of gathering User Requirements. Maybe i am so early to come into conclusions about what tool should be used.

Someone else suggested that I should be finalise the requirements and then think about a tool that can help me get things done. So is it possible that I find what and how things should be analysed before finding a tool? And is it also possible that I find an algorithm for predictive analysis without knowing what would be the results of the tool after analysis.

Comment: Is this not the right place for me to ask this question? Why is the question downvoted?

Comment: This is the right place, provided you ask correctly. See [ask]. Perhaps if you told us what features you liked/disliked about those you googled? What operating system? Free, or do you have a budget? The more (specific) information you can give us, the more that we can help you. I reversed that downvote, sicne you are new, but please help us to help you in future & give more detail in this question if you can (did you ask your professor?)

Comment: Ok. I will surely update my question with all those details. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Good luck with the project  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What criteria should I mainly take into account before selecting a
>   tool for analysing big data?

There are a lot of criterion which are to be taken into account when the tool selection is concerned. The can be:

- Structure of the data. (The data model Ex: Hierarchical, tabular, etc)
- Type of data and what is the problem statement.   (time series, or classification, etc)
- Speed
- Security

> Aim : To develop a software that analyses the data coming from the
>   wind mills and generate reports. The software should be able to
>   predict when a wind mill can fail based on the analysis.

Almost all the existing analytics tools like Python, Julia, R, etc can do this.

> And is it also possible that I find an algorithm for predictive
>   analysis without knowing what would be the results of the tool after
>   analysis.

**Yes.**  The predictive algorithm or technique can be inferred by looking at the data and the contents of the data. **It is not dependant on the tool.**

Some points which I would like to include which I believe would be useful to you:

- Select the database depending on your data, and it's type.  According to your data, a [NoSQL database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) would be more relevant and suitable.
- Select the algorithms and techniques only after you have a clear knowledge about the problem statement and takeaways and also after clearly looking at the data for an [exploratory analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploratory_data_analysis).
- If you want more flexibility, then use a tool/programming language like Python, R and Julia. Else, you can use a tool like Knime, Orange (it has a [Python library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Orange/2.7) too.), RapidMiner, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i will discuss your points with my team. :)

Answer (score 3):

Syncfusion provides a [Big data platform](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/big-data) which is an easy to use Hadoop distribution for Windows. It can help you get started quickly. Syncfusion also provides a [PMML processing library](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/data-science/predictive-analytics) using which you can execute predictive analytic models. There is a [Dashboard platform](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/dashboard) also available that can help visualize the data.

All of the above are available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify.

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will check about Syncfusion today.